# Antd Table in React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am creating a react app using antd in React. I want to create an Antd Table.

I am following this syntax: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-jsx

In the dataSource I don't want separate names like firstName or lastName. I want one array object

```
name:["firstName","lastName"]
```

The problem is I am not able to load or render this data in the `<Column />` tag inside the `<Table />` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can render the column by your self like this

```
<Column
    title="First Name"
    key="firstName"
    render={(text, record) => (
        <div>{record.name[0]}</div>
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Can you please tell, what is the difference between `text` and `record` arguments - documentation as usually says nothing, and logging them into console gives me similar result for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
const columns = [
        { 
            title: 'Name', 
            dataIndex: ['firstName', 'lastname'],
            key: 'firstName',
            render: (row) =><> {row["firstName"]} {row["lastname"]}</>
        }
 ];
```